# python global name 'collections' is not defined even I imported collections

Tags: python, function, collections, import, nameerror

The following is config.py:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
def test_config(fileName):
    tp_dict = collections.OrderedDict()
    with open("../../config/" + fileName, 'r') as myfile:
        file_str = myfile.read().replace(' ', '').split('\n')
    tp_list = []
    for i, x in enumerate(file_str):
        x = x.strip()
        try:
            key = x[:x.index(':')].strip()
            value = x[x.index(':')+1:]
            if key == 'testpoint':
                pass
            else:
                tp_dict[key] = value.strip().split(',')
        except ValueError,e:
            pass
        if i % 4 == 0 and i != 0:
            tp_list.append(tp_dict.copy())   
    return tp_list
```

I'm using the function in another file test.py:

```
import config
a = config.test_config('test.txt')

NameError: global name 'collections' is not defined
```

But if I copy paste the whole code from config.py to the top of test.py, and then use the function, then I have no error(See code below). Can anybody explain this to me please? I'm so so so confused. Thank you very much!

```
"""
This is test.py
"""
from collections import OrderedDict
def test_config(fileName):
    tp_dict = collections.OrderedDict()
    with open("../../config/" + fileName, 'r') as myfile:
        file_str = myfile.read().replace(' ', '').split('\n')
    tp_list = []
    for i, x in enumerate(file_str):
        x = x.strip()
        try:
            key = x[:x.index(':')].strip()
            value = x[x.index(':')+1:]
            if key == 'testpoint':
                pass
            else:
                tp_dict[key] = value.strip().split(',')
        except ValueError,e:
            pass
        if i % 4 == 0 and i != 0:
            tp_list.append(tp_dict.copy())   
    return tp_list
a = test_config('test.txt')
```

Answer (score 12):

Change `from collections import OrderedDict` to `import collections`.

Answer (score 5):

**Option 1:** 
Change

```
from collections import OrderedDict
```

to

```
import collections
```

**option 2:**

Change

```
collections.OrderedDict()
```

to

```
OrderedDict()
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't import collections, you only import **from** collections. Simply write `OrderedDict` instead of `collections.OrderedDict`.

Comment: You're right. But why it doesn't complain an error in the test.py then?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't imported the name `collections`, but just the name `OrderedDict`.
Because of that, you just have to use `bla = OrderedDict()` instead of using the module name.